# How to bring Azure App Registrations from DEV to PROD without recreating them manually?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have an App Registration, which is currently within my DEV environment. It contains a lot of settings (Mainly App Roles). I tried to download the Manifest.json and upload it again to the new registration, but the setting were not written at all.

Is there a better way than recreating the whole App Registration from scratch for the TEST and PROD environment?

Comment: We use a script to generate registrations in all environments, it could be one option.

Comment: @juunas I thought the same way, but I expected there is an easier war to achieve this, because its a challenge nearly every app has at some point.

Comment: The challenge with taking the app registration from one environment to the other is that if it requires permissions to APIs, the service principal object id (mentioned in manifest) is different in each tenant. That's why one of the things our script does is look up the SP ids for e.g. MS Graph API in that tenant. AppRoles and OAuth2Permissions (offered permissions) should copy over fine though, as an example.

Comment: do not forget app roles do also have IDs, which are GUIDs and it is generally good idea to be globally unique (the G in GUID stays for Global after all). So, while, it _might_ work to just copy over the manifest, I would be very careful for the GUIDs. One more thing you cant just copy over are secrets/certs, you have to recreate them too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move comment to answer so that this post can be treated as answered.

Using script to generate registrations in all environments could be one option.

The important thing needs to remember is handling the GUID such as OAuth2Permissions id, appRoles id and so on.